# How to format select cells in a single column of a large dataset

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a table of data that I am importing into excel from a company database. All of the values import into excel easily except for values in one column that have a pattern like below.

```
Example 1

1-5 
2-4 
3-5
```

On import these values are transformed into a "custom" format and end up looking like this [...]

```
Example 2

1-May 
2-April 
3-May
```

I have not had success applying a formatting solution to the entire column mainly because not all values in that column follow the same structure as Ex.1

We intend to perform a dump daily but need to get these values back to their original state (from Ex.2 back to Ex.1). Also, this is a large data set.

I am not making a code request just looking for someone to point me in the right direction as I am stumped.

Thanks for any help in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just configure Excel so that it doesn't automatically attempt to convert numbers to dates by setting the column type to Text?

1. Select the cells that you’ll enter numbers into.
2. Press Ctrl + 1 (the 1 in the row of numbers above the QWERTY keys)
   to open Format Cells.
3. Select Text, and then click OK.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8